# Issues with my PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to practice importing data and then pulling it from an array. I'm using a data set from 538 on avengers as practice (not posting the full list) but can not get the array to display. I've simplified to the point that i'm clearly just missing something stupid and small.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4txCgcRa)
or

```
<?php

$avengers = [
["Henry Jonathan", 52,"Full", "YES"],
["Janet van Dyne",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Stark Tony",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Robert Bruce Banner",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Thor Odinson",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Richard Milhouse Jones", 52, "Honorary", "NO"],
["Steven Rogers",51, "Full", "YES"],
["Clinton Francis Barton",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Pietro Maximof",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Wanda Maximoff",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Jacques Duquesne",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Heracles",48, "Full", "NO"],
["TnChalla",47, "Full", "NO"],
["Victor Shade",47, "Full", "YES"],
["Dane Whitman",46, "Full", "NO"],
["Natalia Alianovna Romanova", 42, "Full", "YES"],
];

$avenger = $avengers[array_rand($avengers)];
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>avergers</title>
<style>
 td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 35px;
 }
 tr {
   wdith 100px;
   font-size: 35px;
 }
 </style>

  </head>
  <body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Years since joining</th>
    <th>Full member?</th>
    <th>Dead?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[3]; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

*updated with suggested changes - still not working

[image: This is my current output]

Comment: Well, for starters, `<?php echo avenger[0]; ?>` is missing a `$`.

Comment: And all the `Full`s in your array should probably be `'Full'` so you're not using a constant. Same thing for the `YES` / `NO`. Maybe use `true` / `false` there. In short, your problem is this is some very wonky code, and it's probably spewing warnings/errors.

Comment: You can use `<?=$avenger[0];?>` instead of `<?php echo avenger[0]; ?>` (it's not going to solve your problem, I'm providing this just in case you find it helpful).

Comment: @Pyromonk That shortcut isn't going to solve any problems with the code.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I know, which is why I said "can use" and not "should use" or "have to use". But thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: -ceejayoz Thanks, stupid mistake

Comment: Pyromonk - Thanks for the tip. Always great to learn shorter code

Comment: @PaulSnowden Your revised code works fine for me. What's "still not working"?

Comment: -Ceejayoz Thanks for the continued help. I attached a screen shot showing my table but empty data.

Comment: @PaulSnowden Copy/paste the code from this question into your PHP file, because it works fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRjx.png

Comment: @ceejayoz I guess it will have to be a mystery for now. I can not get the data to show

Comment: I can also confirm that it's working. Any chance there are other styles affecting the page (it didn't look like it, though). What happens if you just put text into the table cell?

Comment: Looks totally fine here ~ https://eval.in/781460. I'm also guessing a CSS issue. For one thing, you have `wdith 100px` in your `tr` rule which I'm guessing should be `width: 100px`

Comment: @Phil  I added text in the cell and the text appeared but still no array data. I also fixed the width:100px issue without resolution. I have no "hidden" css in this test page

Comment: Are you even running this via PHP? The URL in your browser should look something like `http://...` and **certainly not** `file:///...`. If you view the page source, do you see your PHP code?

Comment: @PaulSnowden are you trying to display everthing in the array or just any random (row) of data? As it is the code displays one row of data under the table headers.

Comment: @Syfer not my question. It looks like OP is just trying to display a single, randomly selected row

Answer (score -1):

I tried to debug the code by echoing the array and number of array but after that it started working. I don't know how it worked but this code is working.
Proof -> http://prntscr.com/f03xt3

Code:

```
$avengers = [
["Henry Jonathan", 52,"Full", "YES"],
["Janet van Dyne",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Stark Tony",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Robert Bruce Banner",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Thor Odinson",52, "Full", "YES"],
["Richard Milhouse Jones", 52, "Honorary", "NO"],
["Steven Rogers",51, "Full", "YES"],
["Clinton Francis Barton",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Pietro Maximof",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Wanda Maximoff",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Jacques Duquesne",50, "Full", "YES"],
["Heracles",48, "Full", "NO"],
["TnChalla",47, "Full", "NO"],
["Victor Shade",47, "Full", "YES"],
["Dane Whitman",46, "Full", "NO"],
["Natalia Alianovna Romanova", 42, "Full", "YES"],
];

$avenger = $avengers[array_rand($avengers)];
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>avergers</title>
<style>
 td, th {
   border: 1px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 35px;
 }
 tr {
   wdith 100px;
   font-size: 35px;
 }
 </style>

  </head>
  <body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Years since joining</th>
    <th>Full member?</th>
    <th>Dead?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $avenger[3]; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Let me know if it works for you too...